# Escape a '+' plus sign in a string to be used in a regex in coffeescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, datatables

I have a regex I'm running to filter rows in a table. The filtering is done in Javascript.

I'm writing coffeescript, but a Javascript solution would be fine -- I can just translate it to coffeescript myself.

I have a value `role` that contains a string I want to filter on using a regex. The problem is the string `role` *may or may not have embedded '+' signs in it.*  Plus signs are special characters for regex searches and need to be escaped in the search string.

I create the regex search string like this (coffeescript):

```
"^"+role+"$"
```

How can I preprocess `role` to escape any '+' signs so the regex works?

Comment: Honest, I looked before posting this. I must've missed the other post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` is far from the only character with special meaning. Here is a function that will escape all the necessary characters:

```
function regex_escape(str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
}
```

Comment: extra credit for a coffeescript version?

Comment: I believe the coffeescript is simply: regex_escape = (str) ->

  str.replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\-]', 'g'), '\\$&')